# PowerBI Jira TIckets Dashboard

Tags: powerbi

Hi all i have a question about PowerBI.

I have two columns for jira Tickets the created date and resolution date.
As an example a ticket created 1/1/2020 and closed 2/2/2020. I have created a measure for the tickets created

Total = DISTINCTCOUNT('search?jql=project=ZUP-SUP&maxResults=1500'[Column1.key])

and according to the weeknumbercreate(create a new column with extracted information form created) the ticket created i show the following result
[image]

I did exactly  the same for the closed tickets.
Now i would like to calculate to show exactly the same diagramm with week numbers and show for every weeknumber how many tickets were in progress. The only way to calculate that is from created day column and closed. Do you have any idea how i could implement that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try calculate this as:

```
TicketInProgress =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'YourTableName'[Column1.key] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( YourTableName[created], YourTableName[closed] ),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( YourTableName[created] ) >= YourTableName[YourWeekSourceColumn]
            && YourTableName[YourWeekSourceColumn] <= SELECTEDVALUE ( YourTableName[closed] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. It is really close to what i need. However i do not know what should i use in the YourTableName[YourWeekSourceColumn]
Due to the only columns i have is the created and closed. Could you help me with that too please.